# An unwanted inline style is added to my body tag

Tags: php, templates, html, css

I have made my theme and installed it on my host, but there is a problem with my body tag. it gets an automatic inline style which looks like below in **Google Chrome**:

```
<body style="">&#65279;&#65279;
```

And in **Safari** looks like this:

```
<body style="">﻿﻿
```

This causes my website show a blank space before my top menu. and It really bothers me. How can I get rid of this unwanted and automatically added inline style?

> For more information, when I delete this styling using the ***inspect
>   element*** section of my Browser(chrome or safari) that blank space disappears. but I don't know how to get rid of that style forever.

Comment: A style attribute shouldn't create blank space, so focusing on it is a red herring. It's more likely to be the `&#65279;&#65279;`, but right now it isn't possible to diagnose the cause based on what you've shown us, we'd need to see the code responsible for displaying those characters, it could even be a CSS issue

Comment: @TomJNowell there is no code that can create those characters.

Comment: Something is generating them, but without seeing any code it's difficult to tell. What is the address of your site?

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for your attention, I just found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot, I realized that elements inside my head tag are shown inside body tag and head tag contains nothing in my generated HTML code.

This happened because I had used UTF-8-BOM encoding and by changing it to simple **UTF-8** everything was fixed.